# Singleton managing a hashMap

Tags: rust

I have the following struct

```
pub struct EntityManager {
    pub entities: HashMap<usize, Entity>,
}

impl EntityManager {
    pub fn addEntity(entity: Entity) {
        EntityManager::singleton()
            .entities
            .insert(entity.Id(), entity);
    }
}

impl_singleton_arc!(EntityManager, EntityManager::new());
```

this is the crate I'm using for the macro
https://crates.io/crates/shared_singleton

The add method throws cannot borrow data in an `Arc` as mutable, I understand we can not pass a mutable reference bcause Arc didn't implement Deref. But how do I approach a situation where I have a singleton that manages a HashMap like that?. I would like to add new entities to that hashMap

Comment: Sorry, I have added the macro.

Comment: Singletons are generally not a good design practice. Even if they're a "Design Pattern™".

Comment: But if you insist, have you tried using `impl_singleton_arc_mutex` instead?

Comment: Fun fact, "singleton" is derived from the Latin word that means "really hecking hard to unit test properly."

Comment: Any alternative to avoid singletons?

Comment: I think purist, blanket statements like "singletons are bad" are to be taken with a grain of salt. Just like all design patterns, they are perfectly suitable for a number of uses cases. As an example, in some of my tooling, I like to populate a `Config` struct and then `Box::leak` it, so that it becomes a static reference that all my code can access. If you combine this with a way to access this `Config`, this is essentially a singleton. This pattern, in my opinion, is helpful and reduces complexity. In the end, this discussion boils down to the questions of "Why is global state a bad idea?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@cadolphs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381179) already mentioned, it seems you want to use a `Mutex` in addition to an `Arc`. As a rule of thumb, you'll need an `Arc<T>` if you want to share something non-mutably between threads, and an `Arc<Mutex<T>>` if you also want to mutate it.

This is explained in more detail in the [Shared-State Concurrency part](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html#similarities-between-refcelltrct-and-mutextarct) of the Rust Book.

```rust
impl EntityManager {
    [...]
    pub fn addEntity(entity: usize) {
        EntityManager::singleton()
            .lock()
            .unwrap(/* You probably also want to return a Result<()> */)
            .entities
            .insert(entity, entity);
    }
}

impl_singleton_arc_mutex!(EntityManager, EntityManager::new());
```